# updating Excel file with formulas using Java

Tags: java, excel

I've created an excel file as below and I want to update it like following:

1- Check if the row has zero value (if yes then make summation of u1 with each row has zero value, if not go to check the next row).

2- Find the average of each row that had zero value after summation.

3- Replace the cell of zero value with the average value.

4- Copy the the updated excel to other excel.

Could any one help please?

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("correct missing Value");
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();

    data.put("1", new Object[]{"ID", "USERS", I1","I2","I3","I4","I5","I6"});
    data.put("2", new Object[]{1, "U1", 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4});
    data.put("3", new Object[]{2, "U2", 3, 0, 2, 4, 2, 3});
    data.put("4", new Object[]{3, "U3", 5, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5});
    data.put("5", new Object[]{4, "U4", 0, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3});

    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Integer)
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
        }
    }
    try {

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Test.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Test.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you've just forgotten a **"** before **I1** in this line :

```
data.put("1", new Object[]{"ID", "USERS", I1","I2","I3","I4","I5","I6"});
```

the correct line  would be :

```
data.put("1", new Object[]{"ID", "USERS", "I1","I2","I3","I4","I5","I6"});
```

And that works

Comment: I just forgot it, but not this what I mean, my code is working. Please see my points 1 to 4 if you could help. thx